# Loading body with exception of sidebar | Turbolinks Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

The givens:

- Running Rails with turbolinks
- I have a multi-level accordion that i use as a sidebar menu with links.
- A section.content that hosts the content of the relevant sidebar menu link
- Using javascript, i've initiated a bootstrap accordion, customised to my needs

Issues faced:

- When i click on the link, the entire body reloads, thanks to turbolinks. This means that sidebar menu is reloaded, but the JS isn't.
- The above situation causes the binded events on the accordion to break as the JS isn't reloaded again on body:change

What i'm looking for:

- A way to make the sidebar load once and turbolinks reload only the section.content on clicking a sidebar menu option.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly,please try with `data-no-turbolink`.

By default, all internal HTML links will be funneled through Turbolinks, but you can opt out by marking links or their parent container with data-no-turbolink.

If you don't want turbolink behaviour, you could use `data-no-turbolink`.

Please see the link  [Opting out of Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#opting-out-of-turbolinks)